# How to upload via samba a file to Amazon S3 server?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, samba

I am pretty new in scripting and I want to write one in bash which will help me automate file upload from my Windows machine to an Amazon S3 server. Do you have any ideas where or how can I start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/minio/mc - mc implements simple shell util commands like cp, ls, mirror.

`mc` supports OS X, Linux and Windows operating systems. We have binaries available to download at https://dl.minio.io/client

Feel free to provide us feedback at https://github.com/minio/mc/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell**

The following example loops through a log directory on an EC2 instance, finds files older than one week, and then archives any non-empty ones to Amazon S3 before deleting the old log file from disk

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem C:\Logs)

{

    if ($i.CreationTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)))

    {

        if ($i.Length -gt 0)

        {

            Write-S3Object -BucketName mylogbucket -Key Logs/$i -File $i.FullName

        }

        Remove-Item $i.FullName

    }

}
```

refer:

[AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to [authenticate / setup your AWS credentials on the command line](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-config-files)

Then you can [create a bucket and upload files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)!